# Is it right to say “in the open sky’ instead of “outdoors”?

Tags: synonyms

Can *outdoors* and *in the open sky* be synonyms?

I find these two terms really confusing.

Comment: You really need to provide sample sentences, since loose phrases like that don’t provide enough context for a quality answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is wrong but I would say "under the open sky."

Comment: I think it is wrong. I don't think you can say 'In the open sky' unless you were flying. Considering that *under the open sky* is a well defined and known phrase (to mean out of doors).

Comment: @Tucker Well it isn't grammatically incorrect and it is used - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+open+sky%2C+under+the+open+sky&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20open%20sky%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20the%20open%20sky%3B%2Cc0 but it seems like it should be used for flight.

Answer (score 2):

You can say *outdoors* or *in the open air*.

Comment: @tchrist. What's wrong with the use of 'strong text'?

Comment: [**The problem with ‘strong text’ is that it looks horrible because of its weight, and messes up the “color” of the page in typographic terms.**](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722) The standard for [the *use–mention distinction* is to set in *italics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use–mention_distinction) or in special cases, sᴍᴀʟʟ ᴄᴀᴘs — or sometimes for longer phrases, using “paired” quotation marks. See Bringhurst. If I had my druthers, the ELU style sheet would map this way `st { font-variant: small-caps; }`. That would look much better.

Comment: I see, so you are suggesting to avoid using it or, should it be a trend for all ELU users?

Comment: Well, there places where bold actually does work better, but not for use–mention cases. In general, my gut tells me it should be rare. It can be useful in quoted blocks at times, though.  A few of us kicked around a style guide.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from *under the open sky*, you could also pluralize the phrase and say *under the open skies*.

> Now get to work, unless you enjoy sleeping [**under the open skies**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=FHkXoxSbzsgC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=%22sleeping+under+the+open+skies%22&source=bl&ots=fbOfyIiGAf&sig=kxPBsaoA6l1Z0KwNIQhjkwhpomM&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=seVvU6XcKZDL0AWPooG4BA&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22sleeping%20under%20the%20open%20skies%22&f=false).

Alternately, and depending on context, consider the French phrase [**à la belle étoile**](http://www.merriam-webster.com), which means:

> *à la belle étoile* [= under the beautiful star] in the open air at night.

Comment: In English, we say [*under the stars* in lieu of *à la belle étoile*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=under+the+stars%2Cunder+the+open+skies%2C%C3%A0+la+belle+%C3%A9toile&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunder%20the%20stars%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20the%20open%20skies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20la%20belle%20%C3%A9toile%3B%2Cc0).  Sometimes we also speak of *dining **al fresco***, to borrow an Italian phrase.

Comment: @tchrist Definitely. But it still means under the open sky/outdoors.

Comment: Yup. The thing that *under the stars* has which *al fresco* or *outside* lacks is the element of night. Sometimes you want the nighttime connotation, and sometimes you do not.

Comment: @tchrist Sure. That's why I pointed up "and depending on context."

Comment: Can we just take another answer and offer it in plural?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can and should use *open sky* — or you could choose one of these terms to express the idea:

- [*upaithric*](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/119626933824411166/)
- [*hypaethral*](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mwc/29691/hypaethral)